# Virtuemart 1.1 product details page

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I need to change the product details page (the one that's linked to from the product title hyperlink in the shopping cart). Trouble is, I just plain can't find the right file. Where is the product details page in Virtuemart 1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else runs into this problem, it turned out to be administrator/components/com_virtuemart/html/basket.php that generates the link.